# hazelcast is not clustered with other ip

Tags: java, hazelcast

I upgraded my hazelcast from 2.x to 3.3.3, but when I started 2 servers at different IPs, it's not clustered.

But it worked when I was using 2.x. It should be like this printing in console:

```
Members [1] {
        Member [172.29.110.114]:5701 this
}
```

I tried using

```
**Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()**
```

and

```
**Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config)**
```

to get the HazelcastInstance for getting the map and other distributed objects. When I used the second one, the config as the parameter, the above message can be printed but the other IP's node can't be shown. when I used the first one without config as its parameter, I can't even see the above message in console.

Anyone knows what's going on here? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable multicast in your hazelcast configuration. Here is how to enabled it with the xml configuration (i.e. `hazelcast.xml`):

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.0.xsd" xmlns=" http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<network>
    <join><multicast enabled="true"/></join>
<network>
</hazelcast>
```

Then create your config this way (`hazelcast.xml` shoud be in the classpath):

```
Config config = new ClasspathXmlConfig("hazelcast.xml")
```

Comment: I'm using the default configuration, which is like this:
<multicast enabled="true">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
The enabled is set to true.

Comment: I updated my answer, you should create the config via `ClasspathXmlConfig` in order for the configuration in the xml file to be used.

Comment: Should I overplay my hazelcast.xml as what you provided? Currently,  I only have my own hazelcast.xml with the management center enabled.

Comment: You can keep your old config (if you have named caches, ...). What I provide is the minimal thing you need to enable nodes discovery.

Comment: is the ip address `224.2.2.3` belongs to one of your instances? because your node have another one `172.29.110.114` and with a different port `5701`!!

Comment: No, I don't have one like 224.2.2.3. That's the default configuration, I just overplayed the hazelcast.xml for enabling the management center. Nothing else is changed. I just checked the old version, 2.x. The default is the same with the 3.3.3 at this line enabling the multicast. So I have no idea what's happening here. Should I need to do more using new version? Which is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: so you just copy/pasted your config! use the one i provide instead of your network config and check if it works.

Comment: It's not working. I tried changing the multicast and tcp-ip in configuration file, still failed clustering.

Comment: Hi, Arbi. Thanks for all your help. I find out what's wrong. It's because I didn't turn off the firewall. It works after I turned it off.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find out what's going on. It's all because the firewall. After I turned if off, it works. Just sharing my experience. And thanks the help of Arbi.